# Bulk Insert/Update with EF6?

Tags: entity-framework

I’m looking for a way to Insert or Update about 155,000 records using EF6. It has become obvious that EF6 out of the box is going to take way to long to look up a record and decide if it’s an insert or update, create or update an object, and then commit it to the database.

Looking around I’ve seen third party apps like EntityFramework.Extend but it looks like they are designed to do mass updates like “Update Table where Field=value” which doesn’t quite fit what I’m looking to do.

In my case I read in an XML doc, create a list of objects from that document, and then use EF to either insert or update to a table. Would it be better off going back to just regular ADO.Net and using bulk inserts that way?

BTW: this is using an Oracle database, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/) package:

```
using EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<Demo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new Demo { InsertDate = DateTime.Now, Key = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Example " + i });
        }
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (Model1 model = new Model1())
        {
            sw.Start();
            model.BulkInsert(data);
            sw.Stop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time for {data.Count} rows: {sw.Elapsed}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Running this on my local HDD drive gives

`Elapsed time for 1000000 rows: 00:00:24.9646688`

P.S. The package provider claims that this version of the bulk package is outdated. Anyhow it's fitting my needs for years now the the package proposed by the author is no longer free of charge.

Comment: The package doesn't support Oracle which is required for this question. Yes, this package work even if is outdated with SQL Server, but doesn't support all inheritance and association. That's why I left the latest version available for now (I'm the package owner)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "free" way to do it, I recommend you to go back to ADO.NET and use Array Bindings which is what I do under the hood with my library.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library support all major provider including **Oracle**

- Oracle DevArt
- Oracle DataAccess
- Oracle DataAccessManaged

This library allows you to perform all bulk operations you need for your scenarios:

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```

*This library will make you save a ton of time without having you to make any ADO.NET!*

Comment: I saw this extension as well but remembered that in the past it didn't support Oracle, which is why I mentioned I'm using it. Unfortunately I'll have to go back to ADO.Net because it's nearly impossible to purchase 3rd party software like that around here. I have to jump through hoops just to get the initial approval and then the software would have to go through compliance approval. It would probably take a least a month to get it and honestly for the price I would probably get denied anyway but at least I got my answer of going back to ADO.Net. Thanks...

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunate that is sometimes so hard to bring some tools in a company :( I know well this feeling and the complexity to make such request! If you need help with Array Bindings, don't hesitate to ask.